# Why does it work in LINQPad but not in my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linqpad

I'm trying different format for a price value in an application (ASP.NET MVC 4), first I tested below code in LINQPad and it worked well (no meaningless trailing zeros). But when I put these code, string.Format("G", value) specifically in my code, it didn't work, trailing zeros appear again!!! Why?

LINQPad snippet:

```
decimal d = 0.3M, d2 = 0.45M, d3 = 13.2M, d4 = 1049M, d5 = 12492.4M, d6 = 2000M;

var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("vi-VN");

Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G}", d));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G}", d2));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G}", d3));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G}", d4));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G}", d5));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G}", d6));
```

LINQPad output:

```
// Output:
// 0,3
// 0,45
// 13,2
// 1049
// 12492,4
// 2000
```

My application output:

```
// Output:
// 0,30
// 0,45
// 13,20
// 1049,00
// 12492,40
// 2000,00
```

UPDATE 1: I tried again following code in a .NET 4 console app, and a ASP.NET MVC 4 (both .NET 4 and .NET 4.5) and all worked well (no zeros). But it still did not work in my application, even when I put them in an empty action. The only different is my application (ASP.NET MVC 4) was created in VS2010 + .NET 4 and upgraded to VS2012 + .NET 4.5 later. Is it issue?

```
decimal d = 0.3M;
string s = string.Format(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("vi-VN"), "{0:G}", d);
```

Comment: Are you displaying the output in your ASP.NET page or writing to the console?

Comment: Also are you positive you're using the latest code on your site?  i.e. you've re-build the project.  Add some debugging lines to verify, like `Debug.WriteLine(culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits);`

Comment: @D Stanley: I were asking for this issue in my ASP.NET MVC 4 code, and above code is just a quick example, that using same format string {0:G}

Comment: The general format uses values from System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo to determine some of how it parses numbers. I'd check there for differences and see if, for example, you aren't setting NumberDecimalDigits, somewhere.

Comment: @Jacob: NumberDecimalDigits is 2 so 16 is outputted as 16,00 is correct, right? But I still don't know what made this difference in my application. Thanks.

Comment: I'd take that as a starting point to start poking at it. Since NumberFormatInfo is culturally dependent, I'd check the behavior out under different cultures (including the InvariantInfo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is just my application problem, not ToString("G"). Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Use {0:G29} instead

```
decimal d = 0.3M, d2 = 0.45M, d3 = 13.2M, d4 = 1049M, d5 = 12492.4M, d6 = 2000M;

var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("vi-VN");

Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G29}", d));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G29}", d2));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G29}", d3));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G29}", d4));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G29}", d5));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:G29}", d6));
```

Reference: [Remove trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros)

Comment: But why?  I tried the OP's code in a brand new console application and it did *not* add trailing zeros.

Comment: The OP is not asking _how_ to remove the trailing zeros, he/she is asking why they're there in the first place.

Comment: I have given a replacement if {0:G} is not working, now let OP decide or comment here.

Comment: Thanks, but it is true that I were not asking for removing trailing zeros. Actually I could do it with {0:0.##} by looked at related posts on SO. But {0:G} is still an issue in my application.