# How to remove decimal part from a number in C#

Tags: c#

I have number of type double.
 double a = 12.00
I have to make it as 12 by removing .00

Please help me

Comment: A double rounded will still give you the .00. Instead if you want just 12, you should try casting it to an int, to shed off the decimal part! Look @ Habib's solution for explicit cast!

Comment: Where do you want to "make it as 12"? `a.ToString()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros may this will help you.

Answer (score 69):

Well `12` and `12.00` have exactly the same representation as `double` values. Are you trying to end up with a `double` or something else? (For example, you could cast to `int`, if you were convinced the value would be in the right range, and if the truncation effect is what you want.)

You might want to look at these methods too:

- [`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx)
- [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx)
- [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx) (with variations for how to handle midpoints)
- [`Math.Truncate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70.aspx)

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion.I have a number which is having value as 12.00.I want to make it as only 12.I want to remove .00.But i m not able to do as I am getting 12.0 with my code                           re = Convert.ToDouble(txtModifedTotalAmount.Text.Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    if (re - Math.Truncate(re) == 0.00)
                       re = Math.Truncate(re);

Comment: @Divya: They're the same value though - 12, 12.0, 12.00, 12.00000 will all have the same representation as `double` values. If you mean it's getting displayed as "12.0" when you format it as a string, that's a different matter - and simply part of string formatting. Or if you'll always get an integer and you only want to *treat* it as an integer, just cast to `int` or `long`.

Comment: i have in sql database `decimal(18,3)` with **input values**: 1.000, 11.124, 127.414, 1377.147, **Expected output:** 1, 11 , 127, 1377, you see i have to remove the scale after decimal, i need to be careful so that i can do calculation using `int` , so should i cast to `int` or use `Math.Round` or split it using string ?

Comment: @stom: What would you want the result to be for 1.9? Or -0.4? Or -0.6? Note that `decimal(18,3)` can store numbers bigger than `int` can...

Comment: for 1.9 i just need 1 and we dont have minus values as its price

Comment: @stom: Okay, so aside from the range issue, just casting to `int` should be fine.

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds: I'm afraid I don't understand what your comment is intending to convey.

Answer (score 45):

If you just need the integer part of the double then use explicit cast to int.

```
int number = (int) a;
```

You may use [Convert.ToInt32 Method (Double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz.aspx), but this will round the number to the nearest integer.

> value, rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If value is
>   halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that
>   is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

Comment: do you attention do **Rounding Error**??

Comment: umm what "Rounding Error" ? there would be no rounding in `(int) a;` *(first part)*, the rounding in `Convert.ToInt32` is not rounder error, instead it is the default [banker's rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default)

Comment: `float f = 1.4f;  int truncated = (int) ((f-(int)f)*100) ;` So, What is your expectation of the `truncated` variable? **40**? Nop, it's 39. Because of the **Rounding Error**

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo, the rounding error is due to arithmetic, because **"`1.4`"` isn't really  `1.4`** (since its a float), *(to test it change the type to decimal like `decimal f = 1.4m;`)*, **but**, all of this is not even related to the question asked.

Comment: I said the pure `(int) a` can not work well. Just it

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo, pure `(int) a` will work, It will be `1` for `1.4f`, exactly `1`, there will be no precision point as it is an integer. So no rounding error as far as casting to `int` is concerned.

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo, one more thing that you can check is `float f = 1.4f; var result = f - 1;` here the result would be something like `0.399999976` that is the nature of floating point number, It has nothing to do with casting to `int` using `(int)`. See: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 37):

Use [Decimal.Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.truncate(v=vs.90).aspx)

It removes the fractional part from the decimal.

```
int i = (int)Decimal.Truncate(12.66m)
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as best answer as it's execution safest

Answer (score 28):

Use [**Math.Round**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx)

```
int d = (int) Math.Round(a, 0);
```

Answer (score 26):

Reading all the comments by you, I think you are just trying to display it in a certain format rather than changing the value / casting it to `int`.

I think the easiest way to display `12.00` as `"12"` would be using string format specifiers.

```
double val = 12.00;

string displayed_value = val.ToString("N0"); // Output will be "12"
```

The best part about this solution is, that it will change `1200.00` to `"1,200"` (add a comma to it) which is very useful to display amount/money/price of something.

More information can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

here is a trick

```
a =  double.Parse(a.ToString().Split(',')[0])
```

Comment: That is culture variant and will work only with locales that use comma for decimal separator. This approach is fragile and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 2):

Because the numbers after point is only zero, the best solution is to use the Math.Round(MyNumber)

Answer (score 0):

//I am doing a basic Calculation here and this works for me.
// it takes values from textboxes and performs the following as far as I understand it. as I have only been coding now for a few months.

double VC2 = Convert.ToDouble(txt_VC_M16_Tap.Text); // converts to double.

double total2 = (VC2 * 1000) / (3.14157 * 14.5); // performs the calculation.

total2 = Math.Round(total2); //Round the result to a whole number(integer)

txt_RPM2.Text = Convert.ToString(total2); // converts result to string and puts it in the textbox as required.

// Hope this helps people that are looking for simple answers.