# ToString() filling Decimal number with zeroes at the right

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

This is a simple question for sure, but I can't find the solution. It's the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104615/best-way-to-display-decimal-without-trailing-zeros-in-c-sharp). In my case, I have a decimal and a string properties on my ViewModel, like this:

```
public string FactorText 
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Factor != 0)
        {
            return this.Factor.ToString();
        }
    }

    set
    {
        this._factorText = value;
    }
}

public decimal Factor { get; set; }
```

When the `.ToString()` acts, it fills the number with zeroes at the right, e.g:

- `1.1` becomes `1.100000000000000`
- `1.9999999999` becomes `1.999999999900000`

... and so on. It fills the remaing of 15 decimal places with zeroes.

I don't really know why and if it have a way to make sure `.ToString()` stops making that.

If this information is relevant, that Factor is mapped with Fluent NHibernate as follows:

```
Map((x) => x.Factor).Column("FACTOR").Precision(30).Scale(15).Not.Nullable();
```

I don't know if this can be the cause of that behaviour.

Thank you in adv.

**Update**: I just can't change the scale and precision. They match the column on the database definition that is `Decimal(30,15)`.

Comment: Well presumably NHibernate is providing a `decimal` value with all those trailing zeroes.

Comment: @JonSkeet but when I stop in a break point here `return this.Factor.ToString();` the Factor value is `1,1`.

Comment: Do you mean in the debugger? Don't assume the debugger is going to use the same representation as anything else, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, in the debugger. Well, in this case I'm confused.

Comment: Basically, don't trust the debugger, I'm afraid. You may be able to dig in to get more details, but I strongly suspect the value really *is* 1.100000000000000m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that this is due to how the database is representing the number. For example, if you insert 1.1 in a SQL Server 2008 decimal(30,15) field and select the result, you will get back 1.100000000000000.

See the comments below, the accepted solution was to use `.ToString("G29")` as found in [How to format a decimal without trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516460/how-to-format-a-decimal-without-trailing-zeros)

Comment: I have suspected that. But I'm could not find out how to prevent that on the mapping or on the .ToString function.

Comment: This question offers a few options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516460/how-to-format-a-decimal-without-trailing-zeros. Most applications use a format string on the page/form/viewmodel to display the desired decimal places. If you just want to remove the trailing zeros, you'll probably have to manipulate the string returned by the ToString call.

Comment: That was what I'm after, it worken with `.ToString("G29")`. Update your answer with this code, and I'll accept.

Comment: Really interesting solution. But/And the most interesting is, how it proves again the fact: calling `ToString` without params should be avoided

Answer (score 1):

`1.1 becomes 1.100000000000000`

```
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 15 places
```

The `.Scale(15)` is what is causing this behavior. Reduce this to the number of decimal places you require.

Comment: The problem is that I need that scale to be 15. I can't reduce it. It is equal to column definition in database: `Decimal(30,15)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.format-Parameters like

string.format("{0:0.0000}",yourvalue");

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```
if (this.Factor.Length < 15) for (int i = this.Factor.Length; i <= 15; i++) this.Factor += "0";
```

Regards.,

k

EDIT: Sorry, try this:

```
return Convert.ToDecimal(this.Factor, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

Comment: I want to remove those zeroes, not adding more.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `Scale(15)` to let the original value be loaded.