# C# String.format a number with dynamic number of significant digits

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

I'm trying to format numbers as strings, but I don't want to use a fixed number of digits. I want to display only the number of fractional digits needed to fully represent the number. For example:

3.00000 would be formatted as "3"

3.12500 would be formatted as "3.125"

3.123456789 would be formatted as "3.123456789"

How can I tell String.format to pay attention to significant figures and produce a string that follows the above pattern?

If string.format doesn't have that ability, is there a class that will let me format numbers in this way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros

Comment: Won't double.ToString() or String.Format("{0}", mydouble) do that by default?

Comment: ["G"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString) is format you are likely looking for as covered in duplicate bug (or MSDN).