# Issue displaying money on view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, decimal

I have the following

```
public decimal? Price {get;set;}
```

When I enter 3000.00 in to the textbox on the view (textbox below)

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label no-padding-right">Price</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "txtPrice", onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)" })
        </div>
      </div>
   <label class="col-lg-4 control-label" style="text-align: left">Decimal format</label>
```

So it would look like this

[image]

It saves in the database as 3000.00 which is expected, but when I return back to the view to edit it the value in the textbox is 3000.0000

I have tried some of the solutions on here

[Remove trailing zeros of decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros)

I think the issue I have is the field on the view is of type decimal not a string, so I'm uncertain on how to format this decimal to remove the trailing zeros so it looks like picture above

Comment: Use the overload that accepts a format string `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, "{0:0.00}", new { ....})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the oveload of `TextBoxFor` that accepts a format string

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, "{0:0.00}", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "txtPrice", onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)"})
```

Side notes:

1. Remove `type="text"`. The html helper already adds this for you (add
   is there a reason why you dont just use the default `id` rendered by
   the helper, which would be `id="Price"`?).
2. Use [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather that polluting your markup
   with behavior - e.g. `$('#txtPrice').keypress(...`

Comment: Correct I should be using the default Id, I'm just use to writing Id etc so I need to get in to the habit and let helper assign the Id's, I'll also change how the keypress is working to. Thanks again