# How to remove zero after decimal point in c#

Tags: c#

> Is there any Math function for this in c#?

If value is 18.00 then i want value 18,
If value is 18.50 then i want value 18.5,
If value is 18.25000 then i want value 18.25.

Comment: Are you talking about converting decimal to string?

Comment: i think this is the answer you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros

Comment: No, i don't want to convert in string. I want decimal value but without 0 after decimal point.

Comment: @IvanChepikov: Java?

Comment: 18, 18.00 and 18.00000000 are all exactly the same value, just represented differently when converted to string. Stated like this, your question doesn't make sense. Add more context/code to show your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Decimal.Round
the documentation is here

[Deciaml.Round Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6be1edhb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert to decimal only use this

```
static decimal? RemoveTrailingZeros(this decimal? value)
{
    if (value == null) return null;

    var format = $"0.{string.Join(string.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat("#", 29))}";
    var strvalue = value.Value.ToString(format);
    return ConvertToDecimalCultureInvariant(strvalue);
}

static decimal? ConvertToDecimalCultureInvariant(this string value)
{
    decimal decValue;

    if (!decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decValue))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return decValue;
}
```

Since the precision of a decimal is 29 hence `Enumerable.Repeat("#", 29)`.

And use it as

```
var result = RemoveTrailingZeros(29.0000m);
```

[image]