# How to check values numbers after the decimal point

Tags: c#

I have tried looking for a similar question here but I can only find how to count the number of decimal places.

What I want to know is: how do I find the value of the decimal places that are >0?

For example, if we have:

```
decimal value = 1.920m;
decimal value2 = 1.900m;
```

How do I check if the values after the decimal point are >0?

I want to be able to check this and restrict the display accordingly so I can display something like this:

```
1.92
1.9
```

Comment: your question answered at this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros#answer-4525983

Comment: Yes sorry, i missed this when searching for my answer. Have marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you want to display the value with the max number of decimal places available and remove the trailing zeros. This is the easiest way to do it:

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("G29")); // Output 1.92
```

Alternate solution (which works for numbers smaller than 0.00001m unlike the above solution). Though this doesn't look as neat as the previous solution using G29, this works better since it also covers numbers smaller than 0.00001:

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.#############################"));  // Output 1.92
```

We are using G29 since 29 is the maximum available digits for a decimal. The G or General Format Specifier is used to define the maximum number of significant digits that can appear in the result string. Any trailing zeros are truncated using this format specifier. You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString).

```
Input:  1.900m
Output: 1.9

Input:  14.571428571428571428571428571M
Output: 14.571428571428571428571428571

Input:  0.00001000000m
Output: 1E-05 (Using first solution G29)
Output: 0.00001 (Using second solution)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am now using .ToString("0.###") and this displays exactly how i want it to :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right you can do something like this:

```
double x = 1.92;
x-=(int)x;
while(x%1>0){
   x*=10;
}
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

**output:**

92

now you can check what you want on this number

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to decimal only use this

```
static decimal? RemoveTrailingZeros(this decimal? value)
{
    if (value == null) return null;

    var format = $"0.{string.Join(string.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat("#", 29))}";
    var strvalue = value.Value.ToString(format);
    return ConvertToDecimalCultureInvariant(strvalue);
}

static decimal? ConvertToDecimalCultureInvariant(this string value)
{
    decimal decValue;

    if (!decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decValue))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return decValue;
}
```

Since the precision of a decimal is 29 hence `Enumerable.Repeat("#", 29)`.

And use it as

```
var result = RemoveTrailingZeros(29.0000m);
```

[image]

Comment: I did try this first but i was not able to run my program after. I must of implemented it wrong or something. But thank you for time, i appreciate it :)