# Mvc Kendo grid number formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

using mvc kendo grid to represent the dat

I have decimal values likes

**Actual O/P**

```
61.05      
16.00
15.92
```

**Expected O/P** This is What i am looking for

```
61.05      
16
15.92
```

I used to display the value like this

```
Format("{0:n2}")
```

**How can I achieve expected o/p, with the help of kendo format**

Comment: Is the value `type` being passed in a number or a string? If it is a string then the formatting won't do anything as kendo will treat the value as a string and not a number. I have fallen foul to this before. As what you have put should work perfectly fine.

Comment: Try using `.ToString("G29")` on your decimal value. This will truncate trailing zeroes on your value. However, if it's possible in your situation to have a value like `0.0001` then you could run into some problems. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros/4525983#4525983) for more info.

Comment: @DavidShorthose type is decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, that should actually work.

You can try the following formatting string as an alternative solution: `{0:0.00}`.

Answer (score 0):

`Format("{0:n2}")` will force all input numbers to 2 decimal places.  If you want to apply decimal places based on the value, use `Format("0:0.##}")` (where the number of decimal places (`#`) is the maximum number of decimal places you will have).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the column to be numbers (for example for sorting, filtering or summing in the grid), then pass string values to the column and do the unusual formatting requirement in the controller.