# Cannot remove trailing zeros from decimal

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove the trailing zeros from a decimal value taken from a database. In particular the value is stored as `800.000` but I need to display `800`, so I need to remove the zeros, I tried:

```
string value = "800.000";
string converted = value.ToString("G29");
```

I get: `800000` but should be: `800`, I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros) and tried also different solution but I get the same result.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As a first clarification I should ask. Why do you have your numbers stored in a database as strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider your culture when converting numbers expressed as strings.

```
string converted = Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("G29");
```

Comment: for italian culture?

Comment: InvariantCulture assumes the point is the decimal separator. So the conversion can identify the integer part from the decimal one

Comment: finally, this seems to work! have a good day steve! I saw you're also italian, nice to meet a fellow countryman

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution:-**

```
 string data = "900.00";
            double result=0;
            double.TryParse(data,out result);
            int ab = (int)result;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use any of the below-mentioned ways -

```
string.Format("{0:G29}", decimal.Parse("2.0044"))

decimal.Parse("2.0044").ToString("G29")

2.0m.ToString("G29")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to get a whole number from a decimal, below can work

```
var decimalValue = 800.000M;
var wholeNumber = Math.Truncate(decimalValue);
```