# How to remove trailing zeros when using doubles in strings with C#?

Tags: c#, string, double, decimal

I have some doubles and I need to print them (in reality I use them in WPF UI) but the resulting string has too many characters (or digits) and I need to show all the significant ones. Removing trailing zeros would help:

```
"1.00000000" => "1", "2.50000000" => "2.5", "205.01280000" => "205.0128"
```

I know I can round() the numbers to a given number of digits but it decreases precision... Is there a function or any way to remove trailing zeros?

Edit: my english was terrible at the time I asked this question. I didn't know the word "trailing" was a thing and so didn't know there was already a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros).

Thanks to all the people who took the time to answer anyway!

Comment: 1.00000000 as a double is already 1, are they string values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string source = "2.4200";
string output = double.Parse(source).ToString();
```

Credits: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros)

Comment: This would depend on the values not exceeding the precision of double, otherwise rounding errors would occur.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you don't actually want to round the numbers, as the target number of decimals is variable. Also given you have `"` around your numbers leads me to believe you are dealing with strings.

You could accomplish what you describe using [`String.Trim(Char[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2)

E.g.

```
string[] vals = {"1.00000000", "2.50000000", "205.01280000"};
char[] trimChars = {'.', '0'};

foreach (var v in vals) {
    Console.WriteLine(v.Trim(trimChars));
}
```

Comment: `1.00000000` will result in `1.` with a trailing `.`

Comment: Updated to trim trailing .

Comment: i don't like treating numbers as strings. This should really be parsed to decimal first. Maybe i'd upvote it if you'd at least use `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator` instead of the hardcoded `.`. Also use `TrimEnd` not `Trim`

Comment: Might be a good idea asking what OP requires if input string is "0.0000" - I would guess "0", rather than an empty string. Another special case reason to avoid treating numeric as strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a constant precision, but you want to remove unimportant zeros, you can use `string.Trim method()`. It has also a variant for end of string only.

```cs
yourString.TrimEnd('0');
```

It will do exactly what you need, using the `TrimEnd` will protect numbers like 0.1 to be trimmed from both sides.

```cs
"1.00000000" => "1", "2.50000000" => "2.5", "205.01280000" => "205.0128"
```

**EDIT:**
Trim also comas to avoid sth like "1.".

```cs
yourString.TrimEnd(new []{'0', '.'});
```

Comment: Might be a good idea asking what OP requires if input string is "0.0000" - I would guess "0", rather than an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

try this simple solution:

```
string number_string = "1.6540000000";
double number = double.Parse(number_string);
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

In that way you can keep using the number_string as a double (performing arithmetical actions on it, etc).