# EF Core - How to round DB values to minimize json?

Tags: sql, json, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

As per subject how I can optimize the json response from an EF Core entity by rounding the values?

In my example I have many number columns in a SQL Server database table (database-first approach) that are of type `decimal(18,9)`. However, most of the data is 0.000000000 - multiplied by number of columns it generates big data load that could be a simple rounded 0 (1 char instead of 11 passed in json).

How to achieve that?

Comment: Do you know which library is used to convert the data to JSON? Is it System.Text.Json (likely for .NET Core 3.1) or Newtonsoft?

Comment: I'm new in .NET Core programming. How to check that? I do not explicitly provide this in the project. I think it's System.Text.Json as can't find "Newtonsoft" anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What's going on

This is basically what happens:

```
HTTP Request -> API Controller -> EF Core Query -> JSON Serialization -> HTTP Response
```

The crucial part is the JSON Serialization. This takes arbitrary data (in your case the result of an EF Core Query) and converts it to JSON. The JSON Serialization is called under the hood by the thing that is calling your API controller's method. It's done by `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` due to the default configuration of ASP.Net core. In order to get `0.0` instead of `0.000000000` you have to change that configuration.

### How to solve

To change the default JSON Serialization configuration of ASP.NET core you have to add some code to the `ConfigureServices()` method in your `Startup.cs` file:

```
// Inside Startup.cs

// Find services.AddControllers() and change it to
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new MyDecimalConverter()));
```

The code above needs the `MyDecimalConverter` class which you need to add to your project.

```
public class MyDecimalConverter : JsonConverter<Decimal>
{
    public override Decimal Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        reader.GetDecimal();

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        Decimal decimalValue,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        // taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7983330/4262276
        writer.WriteNumberValue(decimalValue / 1.0000000000000000000000000000m);
}
```

Comment: This works out of the box :-) and thank you for giving high level overview of the flow, really appreciate it! I thought there will be easier way on the EF Core level to round the data before it will be serialized. The bottleneck i see it is a little bit slow - my "Waiting (TTFB) raised from the 2 seconds to about 10 seconds for a small table.