# ASP Core Minimal API - How do I send decimals without trailing zeros with System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, decimal

I have an ASPNet API server using EF Core 6, and when I use `WriteAsJsonAsync` to write a decimal property it becomes like: `"decimal_property": 0.0000000000000000000000000000`. I don't want to trailing zeros.

I found some solutions of custom converts, but they are all written in `Newtonsoft` rather than `System.Text.Json` so cannot be used like

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(opt =>
{
  opt.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DecimalJsonConverter());
}
```

How to write a `DecimalJsonConverter` can be injected into `WebApplication` directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a converter based on the Sample Basic Converter in [How to write custom converters for JSON serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#sample-basic-converter) and use the extension method from this answer to [Remove trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7983330/9665021) to solve the problem.

The extension method which removes trailing zeros from the decimal:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static decimal Normalize(this decimal value) =>
        value / 1.000000000000000000000000000000000m;
}
```

The json converter utilizing the extension method:

```
public class DecimalJsonConverter : JsonConverter<decimal>
{
    public override decimal Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader, 
        Type typeToConvert, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            reader.GetDecimal().Normalize();

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer, 
        decimal value, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>         
            writer.WriteNumberValue(value.Normalize());        
}
```

Register the converter as you mentioned:

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DecimalJsonConverter());
}
```

[Online Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o03yIz)