# Decimal to string conversion issues

Tags: c#, decimal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# How to remove 0 from the end of a decimal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109494/c-sharp-how-to-remove-0-from-the-end-of-a-decimal-value)
>   [Best way to display decimal without trailing zeros in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104615/best-way-to-display-decimal-without-trailing-zeros-in-c-sharp)

I have decimal variable it has value

```
2.50
2.25
```

How can I convert it into string so I can get

```
2.5
2.25
```

Issue is 2.50 must be 2.5 in string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 2.50);
```

You can also convert it to a string and then do `String.Trim('0');` to trim the trailing zeros off.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like [this example](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) shows:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);         // "123.40"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);         // "123.00"
```

(Basically, using the `String.Format` function)