# Why is that I get zeroes added to decimal values that I am pulling from MS Access database?

Tags: c#, ms-access, decimal, datareader

I originally asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895893/most-efficient-right-practice-to-trim-the-meaningless-zeroes-at-the-end-of-a-dec), but had to ask separately.

Why is it that I'm getting values like 2.01000000 from the database, even though I am storing only decimal 2.01? In my database I see it as 2.01 and not 2.010000. The field in MS Access is of type decimal, and I store it as 2.01 itself. I am pulling the value like this:

```
 while(reader.Read())
        Convert.ToDecimal(reader[i]);
```

I get the value as 2.010000000. Why? Is there a better approach to read decimal values from database? I have set the field's precision as 28 and scale factor as 18..

Comment: Hmm. I'd have thought it would have been 2.010000000000000000 with way more zeros than 2.01000000. Live and learn...

Comment: What is the raw value you get in `reader[i]`?  Is it a string?  If so does it have the extra data?

Comment: @JaredPar reader[i] is an object

Comment: @JonHanna indeed it is.. I just demonstrated with some value.

Comment: @nawfal right but what's it's runtime type?

Comment: @JaredPar if I get you right, its {System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader}. It takes the object overload of Convert.ToDecimal

Comment: Not really what you asked but, if at all possible, I'd switch to another database like SQLite or SQL Server Compact edition. Access is notorious for causing these types of issues.

Comment: @DavidLively thanks, I do have in mind to move to SQLite. I mean I want both versions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to the fact that `System.Decimal` is internally sensitive to degrees of precision, SQL's `decimal` is even more so - with it specified as part of the type.

Scale of 18 and Precision of 28 means there'll be 18 significant digits after the decimal point in the database. (28 digits precision total, 18 after the point, leaves 10 before).

Which access happens to include in the representation it sends to the DAO code.

And decimal happens to note in the parsing done.

And hence you can see this.

Personally, I think this is a flaw; either decimal should express precision as an explicit property, or it should hide it. Maybe there's some justification I can't think of, but none come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

A decimal stores those extra zeros by design.  You could maybe set the level of precision you want by rounding the number to the correct precision:

```
myNumber = decimal.Round(myNumber, 2);
```

This will change the decimal precision to a precision of 2 (and apply rounding).

Comment: But how do I know what precision should I set? I sometimes have a value 2.01 and sometimes 2.0000001. How to deal with this

Comment: Any comparisons of decimals will still work, 2.010000 will equal 2.01.  Whether it holds any amounts of zeros isn't an issue.  The decimal values will even take up the same amount of storage in memory.  If you're converting the value to a string then just do a Trim('0').