# how to remove zeros after decmal from string remove all zero after dot

Tags: android

I'm getting price from server in this format `1299.0000` or `4399.000`  how i will remove all zero after "."   help me please how i will do that how to remove numbers after"." ???? im getting form server price value infloating number how i will remove all zero after "."

how to remove zero after decimal like 1`3400.0000` (remove last 4 zero)

or `2349.00`  (remove last 2 zero)

remove all zero after `"."` how I do that?

```
static ArrayList<String> Category_price= new ArrayList<String>();
Category_price.add(object.getString("price"));

   holder.txtText3.setText("Price: "+Html.fromHtml(ProductList.Category_price.get(position)));
```

Thanks

Comment: Make it an int variable

Comment: Convert it to the appropriate data-type. Use an `int/long` if no decimals are allowed and use a `double` if some decimal precision is allowed (just be aware of relative precision limits - as long as no [or carefully limited] math is performed along the value it should be "OK" to represent a price). Then, *when displaying* the data, use the correct format (to string) conversions to display the appropriate (possibly none) number of digits after the decimal.

Comment: (Of course you should *probably* design to the code to handle a case of data like `99.95` - damn sneaky way of making $100 seem like less.)

Comment: this works in c#, probably in android too? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7983459/93647

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert it into integer type..............................................

oR

Split the string, use decimal point(.) as a spliter character.

OR

```
String val=Html.fromHtml(ProductList.Category_price.get(position));
String val1=val.substring(0,val.indexOf("."));  
holder.txtText3.setText("Price: "+val1);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way..

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(23.086);
    BigDecimal bd1= new BigDecimal(0.000);    
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");    
    System.out.println("bd value::"+ df.format(bd));
    System.out.println("bd1 value::"+ df.format(bd1));
```

Not only for Bigdecimal for decimal also..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String[] separated = CurrentString.split(".");
separated[0]; // this will contain "price"
separated[1]; // this will contain " all your zeros"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String price = object.getString("price");
String price = price.substring(0, price.indexOf("."));
```

If your string is always in that format (2 digits, minus, 2 digits, minus, 4 digits, space etc...) then you can use `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` method of string to get what you want.

Note that second parameter is the `index` of character after returning substring.